# How to unit test nested exception in python?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have the scenario as follows,

```py
class SomeException(Exception):
    pass

class SomeOtherException(Exception):
    pass

def first_fn():
    raise SomeException

def second_fn():
    try:
        first_fn()
    except Exception as e:
        raise SomeOtherException from e
```

I want to check that, somewhere in the chain whether "SomeException" was raised. I have written the unittest as follows,

```py
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_case(self):
        self.assertRaises(SomeException, second_fn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But the unit test fails. But if I do the following,

```py
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_case(self):
        self.assertRaises(SomeOtherException, second_fn)
```

then it is passing.

Is there a way to check whether a particular nested exception was raised in the exception stack trace?

Comment: `second_fn` *didn't* raise `SomeException`, but the exception it *does* raise should have a reference to the `SomeException` in both its `__context__` attribute (because it was raised from a handler that caught `SomeException`) and its `__cause__` attribute (because you explicitly reference that attribute in a `from` clause).

Comment: Python 3.11 introduces [exception groups](https://peps.python.org/pep-0654/) which provide more explicit control over raising multiple exceptions from a single function.

Comment: Using `__context__` and `__cause__`, you'll have to walk what essentially amounts to a linked list of exceptions to see if a particular exception was raised arbitrarily deeply in the call stack.

Comment: @chepner , can you tell how I can unit test the whether __cause__ was a particular exception or not?